# Divide the voltage output of a DC power supply

Tags: power-supply, voltage-divider, potentiometer

I'm a beginner in electronics and I am teaching myself the basics of schematics and electricity.

I designed this simple circuit that allows to choose individually the voltage across 5 resistors and its polarity thanks to potentiometers and DPDT switches. The initial power would be given by a DC power supply tuned at 100V, allowing to choose a voltage difference between 0 and 100 across the resistors.

[image]

This is just an exercise to me, and I would like to know if I made any mistake or if anything should be taken into account before building such a circuit (Although I'm not planning to build it, I would like to know if there are maybe hardware limitations that I didn't consider).

Comment: Hello and welcome.  What's this circuit for?  It's strange to want to reverse the polarity across a resistor (because they're symmetric) and it's strange to have five copies of the same circuit.  What do you learn from this exercise that you wouldn't learn from a single copy of the circuit?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My initial purpose was to get different outputs from a single DC power supply, meaning different voltage differences and polarities that can be distributed to various components or even more sophisticated circuit parts. I have put resistors here just as an example. 
I have randomly reproduced the circuit 5 times, but I guess that you are right and that only 2 versions would have been enough.

Comment: Be aware that the basic circuit is a potential divider: which will give a particular voltage for the setting of P1.  But if the load is a) comparable in size to the bottom part of P1, or b) nonresistive, then your voltage will change.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit schematic that you created will definitely work as a voltage divider and you can also produce different voltages with your circuit. But, the issue is with the practical usage of such a setup. Suppose you decided that you want a 10 V supply using the first (top) resistive divider. In this case, you will set the potentiometer/rheostat in such a way that it gets divided into 90 k\$\Omega\$ and 10 k\$\Omega\$. Your DPDT switch will be connected across the 10 k\$\Omega\$. In this case and you will receive a 10 V output across your load. But what about the current?

In such a setup, your current will be limited to a few mA at best and you would not be able to use it to drive anything. However, such setups are useful as voltage sensors. For instance, you can measure the output voltage of a DC-DC converter using this setup and feed the voltage of your resistive divider to an MCU (assuming you limit the voltage appropriately).

Also, consider the top branch for example. If you set the potentiometer to 0 \$\Omega\$ and accidentally short the two switches, then you are essentially shorting your power supply (assuming that a common ground is used). It can damage whatever supply that you are using. Keep in mind never to short a voltage source.